# Complex algorithm in R with data.tables using previous rows values

Tags: r, data.table

I have my data in the form of a data.table given below

```
structure(list(atp = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1), len = c(2, NA, 3, NA, 
NA, 1), inv = c(593, 823, 668, 640, 593, 745), GU = c(36, 94, 
57, 105, 48, 67), RUTL = c(100, NA, 173, NA, NA, 7)), .Names = c("atp", 
"len", "inv", "GU", "RUTL"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000320788>)
```

I need to form 4 new columns csi_begin,csi_end, IRQ and csi_order. the value of csi_begin and csi_end  when atp=1 depends directly on inv and gu values.

But when atp is not equal to 1 csi_begin and csi_end depends on inv and gu values and IRQ value of previous row
The value of IRQ depends on csi_order of that row if atp==1 else its 0 and csi_order value depends on two rows previous csi_begin value.

I have written the condition with the help of for loop.
Below is the code given

```
lostsales<-function(transit)
{

if (transit$atp==1)
{
  transit$csi_begin[i]<-(transit$inv)[i]
  transit$csi_end[i]<-transit$csi_begin[i]-transit$GU[i]
}
else
{
  transit$csi_begin[i]<-(transit$inv)[i]+transit$IRQ[i-1]
  transit$csi_end[i]<-transit$csi_begin[i]-transit$GU[i]
}
if (transit$csi_begin[i-2]!= NA)
{
  transit$csi_order[i]<-transit$csi_begin[i-2]
}
else
  { transit$csi_order[i]<-0}
if (transit$atp==1)
{
  transit$IRQ[i]<-transit$csi_order[i]-transit$RUTL[i] 
}

else
{
  transit$IRQ[i]<-0
}
}
```

Can anyone help me how to do efficient looping with data.tables using setkeys? As my data set is very large and I cannot use for loop else the timing would be very high.

Comment: You have no column named `IRQ` in your data but it appears in your example/

Comment: Because IRQ is formed on the value of CSi_order else is 0 when atp!= 1

Comment: OK, that makes sense, but look at your first `else` statement. You refer to `transit$IRQ` without having previously created it (`transit$csi_begin[i]<-(transit$inv)[i]+transit$IRQ[i-1]`). So I don't see how it can work as written.

Comment: Yes this is the catch here. I am not able to understand how to refer previous values here as csi_begin<- IRQ(previous row)<-csi_order<-csi_begin( two previous rows). In SAS since it goes row by row so I am ble to do it but not here in R

Comment: Your comment is unclear. Loops by definition go "row by row" .  What is it you want to refer back to?

Comment: Basically at first I would define the csi_begin and csi_end when atp=1 and based on its value csi_order and IRQ vaalue. Now when you move to next row you can define csi_begin based on previous row IRQ value and IRQ value based on csi_order value which is again dependant on previous row csi_begin value. Its a bit complex but easily done when you go from one to other row.But how to do when the operations are vectorised like in R

Comment: @user2786962 I understand your problem now. How big is your dataset.

Comment: My data set  has roughly 23 million rows. So I have splitted it into 8000 different files

Answer (score 1):

Adding the desired outcome to your example would be very helpful, as I'm having trouble following the if/then logic.  But I took a stab at it anyway:

```
library(data.table)

# Example data:
dt <- structure(list(atp = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1), len = c(2, NA, 3, NA, NA, 1), inv = c(593, 823, 668, 640, 593, 745), GU = c(36, 94, 57, 105, 48, 67), RUTL = c(100, NA, 173, NA, NA, 7)), .Names = c("atp", "len", "inv", "GU", "RUTL"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = "<pointer: 0x0000000000320788>")

# Add a row number:
dt[,rn:=.I]

# Use this function to get the value from a previous (shiftLen is negative) or future (shiftLen is positive) row:
rowShift <- function(x, shiftLen = 1L) {
  r <- (1L + shiftLen):(length(x) + shiftLen)
  r[r<1] <- NA
  return(x[r])
}

# My attempt to follow the seemingly circular if/then rules:
lostsales2 <- function(transit) {
  # If atp==1, set csi_begin to inv and csi_end to csi_begin - GU:
  transit[atp==1, `:=`(csi_begin=inv, csi_end=inv-GU)]

  # Set csi_order to the value of csi_begin from two rows prior:
  transit[, csi_order:=rowShift(csi_begin,-2)]

  # Set csi_order to 0 if csi_begin from two rows prior was NA
  transit[is.na(csi_order), csi_order:=0]

  # Initialize IRQ to 0
  transit[, IRQ:=0]

  # If ATP==1, set IRQ to csi_order - RUTL
  transit[atp==1, IRQ:=csi_order-RUTL]

  # If ATP!=1, set csi_begin to inv + IRQ value from previous row, and csi_end to csi_begin - GU
  transit[atp!=1, `:=`(csi_begin=inv+rowShift(IRQ,-1), csi_end=inv+rowShift(IRQ,-1)-GU)]
  return(transit)
}

lostsales2(dt)
##    atp len inv  GU RUTL rn csi_begin csi_end csi_order  IRQ
## 1:   1   2 593  36  100  1       593     557         0 -100
## 2:   0  NA 823  94   NA  2        NA      NA         0    0
## 3:   1   3 668  57  173  3       668     611       593  420
## 4:   0  NA 640 105   NA  4       640     535         0    0
## 5:   0  NA 593  48   NA  5       593     545       668    0
## 6:   1   1 745  67    7  6       745     678       640  633
```

Is this output close to what you were expecting?