# Row by row application in R

Tags: r, data.table

Given below is my data set

```
structure(list(atp = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1), len = c(2, NA, 3, NA, 
NA, 1), inv = c(593, 823, 668, 640, 593, 745), GU = c(36, 94, 
57, 105, 48, 67), RUTL = c(100, NA, 173, NA, NA, 7)), .Names = c("atp", 
"len", "inv", "GU", "RUTL"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I need to perform a row by row operation of the following function

```
I was able to achieve the desired result using for loop
```

Below is the code return

```
for (i in 1:nrow(transit))
{

  if (transit[["atp"]][i]==1)
  {

    transit[["csi_begin"]][i]<-(transit[["inv"]])[i]
    transit[["csi_end"]][i]<-transit[["csi_begin"]][i]-transit[["GU"]][i]
    if (i-2<=0) { transit[["csi_order"]][i]<-0
                  transit[["IRQ"]][i]<-transit[["csi_order"]][i]-transit[["RUTL"]][i]             
    } else
    {
      if (transit[["csi_begin"]][i-2]>= -878)
      {
        transit[["csi_order"]][i]<-transit[["csi_begin"]][i-2]

      } else
      { transit[["csi_order"]][i]<-0}
      transit[["IRQ"]][i]<-transit[["csi_order"]][i]-transit[["RUTL"]][i] 

    }

  } else 
  {

    transit[["csi_begin"]][i]<-(transit[["inv"]])[i]+transit[["IRQ"]][i-1]
    transit[["csi_end"]][i]<-transit[["csi_begin"]][i]-transit[["GU"]][i]
    if (i-2<=0) { transit[["csi_order"]][i]<-0
                  transit[["IRQ"]][i]<-0
    } else
    {
      if (transit[["csi_begin"]][i-2]>= -878)
      {
        transit[["csi_order"]][i]<-transit[["csi_begin"]][i-2]
      }  else
      { transit[["csi_order"]][i]<-0}
      transit[["IRQ"]][i]<-0
    }}
}
```

Can anyone help me how to get rid of this for loop and how to write the same code for a data table so that it is very efficient.

Comment: It is because of the `[i-1]` and `[i-2]` extractions. `apply` basically converts your df into a bunch of vectors so those indices are not meaningful. If you need to be able to reference multiple rows, you probably need a for-loop.

Comment: Please don't post the [**same question**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20656031/1478381) twice. Instead, edit your original.

Comment: You do not get a value of "x" passed by apply that will be a list. It is an atomic vector. It's always a vector, so using "[[" will fail. (Not to mention the fact the there is no such thing as [i-1] or [i-2] for a named vector element in what is passed by apply.) Delete this post and go back to the original and addres these problems as well as the other ones by editing your question.